# Best cubing algorithm to learn after beginner's

Tags: rubiks-cube, speedsolving

I'm a new fan of cubing. I've recently bought a speed cube and for now I have only mastered the beginner's method and solve it in barely a minute and a half (which is way over what a speedcuber is supposed to do). 
So I'm wondering, is there any recommended method to learn after the beginner's method in order to improve my time ?

Comment: While still slower than a typical speed cuber, you can bring your time down to ~40sec using your current method with nothing more than repetition.

Comment: There are different methods to learn after the Beginner's Method, but the most commonly used one is CFOP. Btw, I can recommend checking out the [Cubers-reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cubers) if you have any more questions and to meet other people with the same hobby. :)

Comment: @Chowzen Vaseline is really really bad for speedcubes - it eats the plastic away and although it may seem okay and smoother initially, your cube will eventually be unusable. Rubik's brand cubes have really tough plastic, so the vaseline method works fine with them to speed up the breaking in process, but for speedcubes vaseline is a big no.

Comment: Everywhere I hear 'If you want to get better learn this whole method'. For example the mentioned Fridrich method for f2l already seems to need 44 algorithms. Someone who just learned the beginner method may literally just know 6 algorithms. If there are another 6 or so that make a big impact (that are a subset of an ultimate target solution so you won't learn extra bad habits) that could perhaps be a nice addition to the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with @mchoy25 that you can bring your time down much more. Things like single finger turning, properly lubricating the cube, and knowing what the back of the cube looks like without rotating the cube will improve your time much more than switching algorithms. That said, if you want to switch to more complicated methods then I'd look up F2L. Basically, from beginner to master you'll just be reducing the number of steps taken while massively increasing the number of possible algorithms to perform/memorize for any given step

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go for speedcubing, it's NOT recommended to learn the beginner's method at all. You end up trying to unlearn the bad habits that you picked up from the beginner's method. However, the most commonly learnt speedcubing method (and hence has a lot of resources available for it) after the beginner's method is the Fridrich method. In less than a couple of weeks you should be sub 40 easily.

Comment: in the question it says they already learned beginner's method >.>

Comment: Yes, and that's quite a shame.

Comment: you're not going to find someone who can speedcube but hasn't learned the beginner's method

Comment: That is definitely untrue - I've taught people to speedcube from zero to Fridrich.

Comment: I’m glad you felt so strongly about this that you replied to a 3-year-old comment.

Comment: An old comment it may be, but false it is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of the answer to this question but you should be able to bring your time down way more. Using the beginner's method I got my time to around 56 seconds.

From what I've heard from other people though (and what I've experienced), you should probably try learning CFOP next. As other people have said, the bad habits from learning the beginner's method will be annoying at first but I think it's still a good idea to learn the beginner's method for the sake of getting a grasp of the fundamentals.